# Emit javascript debugger; from Script Sharp

Tags: script#

I want to emit just debugger; to javascript from c# script sharp code.
I realize I could write **Script.Literal("debugger")**.
I'd rather not use Script.Literal unless absolutely needed.
I'd prefer to write something like Debugger.Break(); in c# with the emitted javascript being just debugger;
Is there some sort of attribute that will let me do this if I create an Imported Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a hack, but it works. You gotta get creative when what you want to do isn't officially supported, right?

It's based on the way Script.Alert works and makes use of the `[ScriptAlias]` attribute to include a JavaScript comment. Luckily ScriptAliasAttribute passes along the value provided exactly and doesn't sanitize it in any way.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

    [GlobalMethods]
    [IgnoreNamespace]
    [Imported]
    public static class Debugger
    {
        [ScriptAlias("debugger;//")]//must comment out ();
        public static void Break()
        {
            //this outputs -  debugger;//();
        }
    }
}
```

So, using the above code, you can write `Debugger.Break();` in your C# code, and you'll get `debugger;//();` in the JavaScript emitted. A little ugly, but it works.

Comment: Wow this is a hack if I've ever seen one but way to think outside the box! Thanks!

Comment: Ran into an issue using the comment tags when using the non debug script. Calling a method instead  [ScriptAlias("debugger;new Date")] which will emit debugger;new Date();

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. Clever! Something like `debugger;console.log` would probably work too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Debug.Fail ... which is what would be the norm for c# code.

Comment: Do you mean name the class Debug and the method Fail or do you mean you put something in Script# that can be called with the code `Debug.Fail();` ?